# How to group elements in the adminpanel (custom type posts)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Good afternoon. Prompt huk for group the admin dashboard to submenu.

As it looks now

[image]

As I want that it looked

> |Cyprus (main)
>
> |-->News (sub)
>
> |-->Cities (sub)
>
> |-->Villages (sub)
>
> |-->Stories (sub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `show_in_menu` paramiter when registering the custom post type.

```
$args = array(
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=a_master_post_type',
  'menu_position' => 30,
  'has_archive' => true
);

register_post_type('your-post-type',$args);
```

Instead of using one post type page as the main link you could create a new menu item and reference this in each of the post type's `show_in_menu` paramiter.

```
'show_in_menu' => 'your-custom-menu-slug.php'
```

and then create a new menu item.

```
function add_your_menu() {
  add_menu_page( 
    'Multiple Post Types Page', 
    'Multiple Post Types',     
    'manage_options', 
    'your-custom-menu-slug.php', 
    'your_menu_function');
    // add_submenu_page() if you want subpages, but not necessary
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_your_menu');
```

This information was gathered from experience and the examples are taken from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37747) question on the wordpress stack exchange.